# How to trigger function when any incoming emails in Office365 mailbox?

Tags: office365

We are moving all our users to Office 365 mailboxes.  We have a requirement to do something when an email is received (before it reaches the users mailbox).  Currently, on our on-premise exchange server, we have transport rule setup to forward all incoming emails to a drop folder.  What we would like to do is:

1. All incoming emails (for all users)
2. Call an Azure function with the incoming email's ID and TO (recipients)

Thanks in advance.